# DIV does not stay inside another DIV

Tags: html, css, smarty, opencart

I have been wrestling with this issue for an hour and I dont make any progress at all so here I am.

The problem I am facing is that I have a div that just does not stay inside another.

Heres a picture explaining what I have and what I want:
http://www.upload.ee/image/2086206/whatiwant.jpg

Live Version: http://haavistu.eu/shop/index.php?route=product/category&path=74_61

What I have done so far:
I placed the price generating code and all of the buttons inside a `div` classed `stuffholder`. I then floated the `div stuffholder` to the right.

I tought I was done but what I have is visible from the picture.

All the relevant code:

```html
<div class="product-list">
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
    <div>

    <div class="image">
        <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
            <img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" />
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="stuffholder">
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
                <div class="price">
                    <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
                    <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <div class="cart">
            <a onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button"><span><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="wishlist">
            <a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="compare">
            <a onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>

      <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
      <div class="description"><?php echo $product['description']; ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

  </div>
```

Sorry for the awful intending. The image, name and description part seem to work fine.

Heres the CSS

```html
.product-list > div {
    overflow: auto;
}
.product-list .right {
    float: right;
}
.product-list .image {
    float: left;
}
.product-list .image a {
    display: block;
}
.product-list .image img {
    display: block;
}
.product-list .stuffholder {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
.product-list .price {
}
.product-list .price-old {
    display: block;
}
.product-list .wishlist a {
    display: block;
}
.product-list .compare a {
    display: block;
}
```

Removed the completely irrelevant stuff away.

When I watch the source code it all creates, I see:

```html
<div>
    <div class="image"><a href="xxx/shop/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=74&amp;product_id=50"><img src="xxx/shop/image/cache/data/prosessorit/Core-i5-2500K-and-Core-i7-2600K-Review-614x614-80x80.jpg" title="Intel Core i5-2500K 3,3Ghz Prosessori - LGA1155" alt="Intel Core i5-2500K 3,3Ghz Prosessori - LGA1155" /></a>
                            <img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-5.png" alt="Perustuu 1 arvioon." />
            </div>
  <div class="name"><a href="xxx/shop/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=74&amp;product_id=50">Intel Core i5-2500K 3,3Ghz Prosessori - LGA1155</a></div>
  <div class="description">
    Intel’s most popular family member is more adaptable than ever and unlocked. The 2nd generation..</div>

    <div class="stuffholder">
        <div class="price">198,00€</div>
        <div class="cart">
            <a onclick="addToCart('50');" class="button"><span>Lisää koriin</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="wishlist">

            <a onclick="addToWishList('50');">Lisää toivelistaan</a>
        </div>
        <div class="compare">
            <a onclick="addToCompare('50');">Lisää vertailuun</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Accordingly to source code, it all should work nicely. Can anyone tell me when the `div price` does not stay inside `div stuffholder` and how to fix it?

Comment: It would be more helpful to see the generated HTML than the PHP code

Comment: Since this is a CSS problem, and not a PHP problem; the generated HTML would be more helpful than the PHP.  Could you post that instead?

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle for it (www.jsfiddle.net)? It'd be easier for everyone to edit and show you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: hidden;` in the parent

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. Which parent?

Comment: .product-list > div {
    overflow: hidden;
}

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your live example's source code, it does not reflect what your question indicates:

```
<div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="cart">
        <a onclick="addToCart('50');" class="button"><span>Lisää koriin</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="wishlist">
        <a onclick="addToWishList('50');">Lisää toivelistaan</a>
    </div>
    <div class="compare">
        <a onclick="addToCompare('50');">Lisää vertailuun</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="left">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="http://haavistu.eu/shop/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=74_61&amp;product_id=50"><img src="http://haavistu.eu/shop/image/cache/data/prosessorit/Core-i5-2500K-and-Core-i7-2600K-Review-614x614-80x80.jpg" title="Intel Core i5-2500K 3,3Ghz Prosessori - LGA1155" alt="Intel Core i5-2500K 3,3Ghz Prosessori - LGA1155"></a>
        <img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-5.png" alt="Perustuu 1 arvioon.">
    </div>
    <div class="price">198,00€</div>
    <div class="name">
        <a href="http://haavistu.eu/shop/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=74_61&amp;product_id=50">Intel Core i5-2500K 3,3Ghz Prosessori - LGA1155</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        Intel’s most popular family member is more adaptable than ever and unlocked. The 2nd generation..
    </div>
</div>
```

The price is in **left** div, see?

Comment: I just realised that a little Javascript code is controlling wether the list is shown as a list or as a grid. I suspect that it is what is causing it. Will have to look.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it with what you have now is to add a few rules to your `.product-list .price` selector.

```
.product-list .price {
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative; /* this is new */
  right: -85px;       /* this is new */
}
```

However, it would probably be better if the price was in the document right before the checkout button rather than where it is now.

Comment: I think I am beginning to crack this nut down. Just checked my code again and there is a List and a Grid way of looking at the items and a little Javascript is controlling it and placing the elements around. I think that is what is controlling it.

I will give your code a try thought.

Answer (score 0):

The [page you linked to](http://haavistu.eu/shop/index.php?route=product/category&path=74_61) has a different layout than the one you posted.  There are two DIVs.  A `div.left` and a `div.right`.  Your price is in the one labeled "left"... which is why it goes to the left, and not the right.  Simply moving it will fix the problem.

The code from that page looks something like this.  (After fixing it.)

```
<div class="right">
  <div class="price">
    1 033,00â‚¬
  </div>

  <div class="cart">
    <a class="button" onclick="addToCart('51');"><span>LisÃ¤Ã¤ koriin</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="wishlist">
    <a onclick="addToWishList('51');">LisÃ¤Ã¤ toivelistaan</a>
  </div>

  <div class="compare">
    <a onclick="addToCompare('51');">LisÃ¤Ã¤ vertailuun</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="left">
  <div class="image">
    <a href=
    "http://haavistu.eu/shop/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=74_61&amp;product_id=51">
    <img alt="Intel Core i7-3960X 3,3GHz Prosessori - LGA2011" title=
    "Intel Core i7-3960X 3,3GHz Prosessori - LGA2011" src=
    "http://haavistu.eu/shop/image/cache/data/prosessorit/Intel%20Core%20i7-3960X%203,3GHz%20-%20LGA2011-80x80.jpg"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="name">
    <a href=
    "http://haavistu.eu/shop/index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=74_61&amp;product_id=51">
    Intel Core i7-3960X 3,3GHz Prosessori - LGA2011</a>
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    The 2nd generation Intel Core i7-3960X Processor Extreme Edition is super-smart,
    ultra-threaded, ..
  </div>
</div>
```